# ajax failing getting data from pre element after it gets filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

The thing is that i have an embedded python interpreter and after a user presses "Run", the output from interpreter gets transferred to a pre element. I want to take that data from pre element and send it to django server through AJAX. The problem is that even after assigning of that data to a variable, django gets nothing. Also i can start interpreter and AJAX script only after pressing "Run", both work work with onclick. I am using POST request.

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#run').click(function(){
   var input_string = String(document.getElementById("output").innerHTML);
   alert(input_string);
   $.ajax({
     url: '/courses/python3/lesson_validate/{{ lesson_number }}/',
     data: {"text": input_string, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
     dataType: "json",
     type:"POST",
     success: function(data, textStatus){
       alert('get_response');
       alert(data);
     },
     error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
     }
   });
 });
});
```

`

So that code works perfectly

`var input_string = String(document.getElementById("output").innerHTML);
 alert(input_string);`

but when i try to use that variable in ajax, server fails to get it.
I tried using `async: false`, it doesn't change anything.
This is view code:

```
`def lesson_validate(request,lesson_number):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    out_compare = Lessons.objects.get(id=lesson_number).lesson_output
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get('text') == out_compare:
        text = "they are equal"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(text), content_type='application/javascript')
    else:
        args['testtest']=request.POST.get('text')
        return render_to_response('course_lesson.html', args,  context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
```

After i check `request.POST.get('text')` it is empty

The question is how can i get data from ajax, from a variable assigned before, not just from a sting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're sending JSON to the server in that request, so to get the variables in Django you'd need to do:

```
def lesson_validate(request,lesson_number):
  import json 
  data = json.loads(request.body)
  text = data.get('text')
  # Do stuff.
```

Comment: This is what firebug tells me now:
the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
i tried .decode(), and this is what i get Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: My bad. You're not actually sending json currently. For my answer to work you'd have to wrap the data you're sending to the server in a call to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: If i use `JSON.stringify()` and wrap all data, i get csrf error, because i use token in data to send it to server